# UITableView with contact images in Monotouch scrolls very slow

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, contacts

I'm developing a contact app for the iPhone using MonoTouch. I am using a custom UITableViewCell, which shows the contact image (ABPerson.Image), contact name and some other info. 
I am using the following code when the contact image is be loaded:

```
//CustomTableViewDataSource class
if (person.HasImage)
    customCellController.LoadImage (person.Image);


//Custom cell controller class
public void LoadImage(NSData data)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (p => this.loadImage (data));  
}
private void loadImage(NSData data)
{
    UIImage image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
    InvokeOnMainThread(delegate
    {
        this.imageView.Image = image;
    });
}
```

This code works fine, but scrolling is way to slow. Does anybody have a better idea to load the contact images?

Thanks,
Danny

Comment: How are you creating the cells for this table?

Answer (score 2):

There could be a lot of problems with your implementation, the code snippet is not enough to figure out what is wrong.

You can look at the image downloader that is part of MonoTouch.Dialog as it supports this scenario, while loading the images from the network or a local file system cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check the MonoTouch.Dialog project!

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent blog on this topic which can be found [here](http://simon.nureality.ca/simon-says-monotouch-downloading-images-like-appstore-app-in-less-than-50-lines-with-coreanimation-transitions/).

Which covers this topic - it appears what you're doing is very similar, except your actually loading the images in the customCellController itself. In this example, they're called the `LoadImage()` and `loadImage` in the datasource and passing in the cell object, rather than doing the computation in the cell itself. You may find this will help speed up your scrolling.

Comment: Hi, this topic covers downloading an image through the internet. In my code I am not downloading an Image, but I set the image from the Contact on the iPhone itself.